# Rails Newbie: Recommendations for error handling in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling, design-guidelines

Sorry if the question is obvious, I am only starting to work with Rails.
I have a following code in several controller methods now:

```
respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to(edit_project_url(@project), :notice => '#{user.name} added to #{role}.') }
        format.js
    else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.js #...
    end
end
```

So the question is, what is the best way to do the same thing for errors in all methods?
Is it recommended that I use `save!` and handle it in `rescue_action`?

Or should I do my own `respond` method and pass `save` in a block?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's often more convenient to use the exception-raising variant of save and rescue that later in the block than to branch like that. The advantage to exceptions is they'll bust out of transactions.

```
def create
  @project.save!

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(edit_project_url(@project), :notice => '#{user.name} added to #{role}.') }
    format.js
  end

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.js #...
  end
end
```

You'll find that it gets really tricky to wrangle your way out of a pile of nested `if` statements when trying to save more than one object at a time, but a simple `rescue` for exceptions will handle it neatly.

```
def create
  Project.transaction do
    @project.save!
    @something_else.save!
    @other_stuff.save!
  end

  # ...
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
  # ...
end
```

If any one of those saves blows up you'll get an exception. To ensure that all of them are displaying validation errors you might have to call `.valid?` on each to prime them or you will have those after the failure left untested.

Comment: This seems a good idea, but why scaffold does not go this way? Also I assume you recommend to use `rescue_action` if there are several such methods?

Comment: Ok, I am going to assume you meant a `rescue_from` or `rescue_action_in_public` handler for multiple methods, in which case Chubas reply here is a subset of this one and I should accept this one as an answer.

Comment: As a general rule I use `rescue_from` for things that cannot be easily recovered from, and `rescue` when I can handle it. When a `create` fails, typically you just render the `new` form again. Something more abstract generally returns a pretty "Uh oh" page.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a bad thing to use the `if @object.save` pattern. However, if you are doing exactly the same for all your actions on your controller, you can define a [`rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html) action.

[Something like](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html)

```
class MyController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do
    render :action => edit
  end
end
```

Comment: Yep, that was one of my options, but this kind of needs `!` version, does not it? Do you know why scaffold does not go this way by default? It seems better to me.

Comment: Your and and @tadman both seem to complement each other, so I would accept both if I could, but unfortunately I had to chose one.